# "invalid enumerant" when creating 16-bit texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm attempting to create a 16-bit texture to hold the height-map for my terrain patches, however both of the following are returning "invalid enumerant" errors. The CHECK_GL_ERROR() macro shows the gluErrorString as a message and breaks if glGetError returns something other than GL_NO_ERROR.

```
CHECK_GL_ERROR( glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE16, width_, depth_, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 /*data_.raw_data()*/ ) );
CHECK_GL_ERROR( glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA16, width_, depth_, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 /*data_.raw_data()*/ ) );
```

I have a created texture bound to the GL_TEXTURE_2D target, and have the same error with and without:

```
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2 );
```

I'm using an OpenGL 3.2 context, NVIDIA CUDA dev drivers 286.16 on a GTX 560Ti. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a [core context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts), then that should be expected. There's no `GL_LUMINANCE` or `GL_ALPHA` [image formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) anymore.

If you want to emulate the effect of them, you need to create a single-channel image format. So `GL_R16` should be your internal format. Then set up a [texture swizzle mask](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) on the texture object, so that the single Red channel is broadcast to either RGB or Alpha, as you see fit.

It's really better this way.

Comment: Fantastic, thank-you :)

As it is now clear the OpenGL man pages I have been using are not up to date with the latest specifications, is there a similar reference which covers the new core and compatibility specifications?

Comment: @PsychoLogic: If you're talking about [this reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/), they specifically say they're for 2.1. The 4.2 core reference is available [on the Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Reference), or [on the website](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/). Note that this is just core; compatibility specs aren't covered.